# jQuery: "class" with Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying make a class in jQuery for the first time, but something is going wrong.
This is some part of my code:

```
$.Tables.prototype = {
    lineColor: 1,
    items: [],

    mountTable: function(ObjItems) {
        trClass = ((this.lineColor%2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
        html = '<tr role="row" class="' + trClass + '">';

        $.each(ObjItems, function(key, val) {
            html += '<td>' + val + '</td>';
        });

        html += '</tr>';

        this.lineColor++;
        this.items.push(ObjItems); console.log(this.items);

        return html;
    }
}
```

The console returns an empty array, i don't see why.
But if I use "push" two times, it works:

```
$.Tables.prototype = {
    lineColor: 1,
    items: [],

    mountTable: function(ObjItems) {
        trClass = ((this.lineColor%2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
        html = '<tr role="row" class="' + trClass + '">';

        $.each(ObjItems, function(key, val) {
            html += '<td>' + val + '</td>';
        });

        html += '</tr>';

        this.lineColor++;
        this.items.push(ObjItems);
        this.items.push(ObjItems);
        console.log(this.items);

        return html;
    }
}
```

Someone have an ideia why this happens?

--
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post a working sample with https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I don't no why in jsFiddle is working fine! https://jsfiddle.net/kaiunido/6yzqkh9c/
The difference between jsfiddler and my files is all js code is in the same location in the jsfiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I think solved this problem creating a init method.

```
init: function() {
    this.items = [];
},
```

and calling a method following declaration:

```
var table = new $.Tables();
table.init();
```

Thanks.